# Display DOM element on click of hyperlink

Tags: jquery, dom

I am making my way through learning how to use jQuery effectively, but I am having some trouble with the smallest bit of code here, and I'm seeking some help.

```
$(".showHideLink").on("click", function() {
var id = $(this).attr("id");
$("."+id+" comments").show();
});
```

Ideally, this would make the elements with the classes "id" & "comments" show.  This is part of an evaluation form, with ~60 different items that need a qualifying value, but the quantifying information is optional, so I have chosen to hide the `textarea` unless the evaluator chooses to enable it.

I'm not sure if my error is in concatenation or if I'm missing the mark completely.

If it helps, here is a referring link to see if this is where my error is originating.

```
<p class="showHide"><a class="showHideLink" id="1" href="#">Enter Comments</a></p>
```

And here is the element that I'm trying to "show."

```
<p class="1 comments">Comments:<br><textarea cols="50" rows="3"></textarea></p>
```

I've been searching for a bit, but I've not been able to find any other questions with answers that seem to specifically fit my need. Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: `$("."+id+".comments").show();` But it's very bad idea to give classes like 1, 2, etc. If it's unique, use id, not class.

Comment: As `dfsq` mentioned, your id concatenated selector looks like `$(".1 comments")` which isn't really valid - it's looking for an element `<comments>` that's a child of an element with class `.1`. By doing `$(".1.comments")` it means "An element that has both class `1` and class `comments`.

Comment: @dfsq Thank you, I simplified it down for the posting, I'll be appending some other description to the numeric identifier. Many thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting a `<comment>` element based on your selector. You should instead use: `$("." + id + ".comments")`, because what you want is to select for the element with a class of `1` **and** a class of `comments`, i.e. `.1.comments`.

```js
$(".showHideLink").on("click", function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $("." + id + ".comments").show();
});
```

```css
.comments {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="showHide"><a class="showHideLink" id="1" href="#">Enter Comments</a></p>
<p class="1 comments">Comments:<br><textarea cols="50" rows="3"></textarea></p>
```